# Meaning of "would be" in "announced that he would be leaving Google"

Tags: future-tense, reported-speech, will-would

> On August 3, 2012, Bloch announced that he **would be** leaving Google.

<sup>([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Bloch))</sup>

What I can understand:

- > I will leave Google.
- > I would leave Google.

What's the meaning of:

> would + be + verb-ing

Comment: That is reported speech. 'Will' is backward shifted to 'would'. Actual form is 'will be Ving'. There is no conditional in that sentence.

Comment: While the speech here is "reported speech," the actual tense is a conditional.  If you don't like the word "conditional," that is fine, but that is the actual conjugation is a conditional speech: [conditional continuous](https://www.ef.com/ca/english-resources/english-grammar/tense-changes-when-using-reported-speech/), [reported speech](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/reported-speech-1-statements)

Answer (score -1):

> would + be + verb + ing

This is called the [conditional present progressive](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/present-continuous-conditional/) or conditional present continuous tense.

Comment: There is no such thing as 'would Ving' but 'would be Ving'. Also, this sentence is not a conditional one.

Comment: That was a typo. The tense is the conditional present progressive.

Comment: ''This form is common in type 2 conditional sentences. It expresses an unfinished or continuing action or situation, which is the probable result of an unreal condition.'' This is the definition from the webpage you linked. Now check wikipedia the that lovespring linked. Is that a conditional sentence or reported speech?

Comment: It is both. The reported speech uses the conditional present continuous instead of the future continuous.

Comment: No it isn't. Reported speech is backward shifting (over generalized). Original sentence of that person is: I will be leaving X. This is not a conditional sentence. There is no condition at all in this sentence. However, by using reported speech the author uses backward shift and replaces ''will'' with ''would''.

Comment: If it was a sentence like in the situation I will give, than I can accept that answer.  Imagine right now I am having an interview with that person. I ask; What would you do if Google decided to do this?  His answer: ''I would be leaving Google''. This is conditional.

Comment: There does not have to be a condition for a sentence to be conjugated in the conditional. The speech does not change what the conjugation is. The direct speech is not the sentence that was quoted. [Examples](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/tense-changes-when-using-reported-speech/)

Comment: Do you understand what a ''condition'' is? Structure ''looks'' exactly same. But their job is completely different.

Comment: It's even sillier to call "would leave" the _conditional tense_ than it is to call "will leave" the _future tense_. Since both of them are structurally indistinguishable from modal form such as  "can leave" and "may leave", and both have a range of meanings only some of which are temporal, these are unhelpful misnomers. I call the _conditional tense_ "even sillier" because it is not even used in the protasis of conditional sentences in standard English (though it is in some non-standard forms). I suspect the term arises because of a misapplied parallel with French.